# How do I center a div that is scaled using -webkit-transform

Tags: css

How do I center vertically and horizontally a div that is affected to a scale transformation using -webkit-transform.

Just as an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/yL46b7Lo/

```
<body>
  <div class="center" style="-webkit-transform: scale(0.20);">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dgZ-K87NcwQ" width="2000" height="1200"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>

div.center iframe {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Change your jsfiddle link from https to http, otherwise there is a cross domain error with the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Transform the iframe scale instead of the div. <s>Set the div position as absolute.</s>(not necessary)

```
.center{
//position:absolute;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
iframe {
-webkit-transform: scale(0.20);
}
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gp660rzc/